# Oracle SQL: standard analytics functions vs modeling clause

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, model, analytics

I would like to 1) identify gaps in my dataset by the lower boundary of the 2nd std deviation and 2) evaluate the average / median / stddev of the percentage share within a given group for the remaining values.

As a beginner/intermediate in Oracle SQL I would like to get some thoughts from experts regarding two competing query methods to achieve the described goal:

Using Oracle's "famous" model clause:

```
select intv, avg, stddev, med from
(
select * from test
MODEL
PARTITION BY (INTV)
DIMENSION BY (ROWN, CASE WHEN (VAL < AVG(VAL) OVER (PARTITION BY INTV) - 2*STDDEV(VAL) OVER (PARTITION BY INTV)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END flag) 
MEASURES (VAL, val/sum(val) over (partition by rown) prt , 0 avg, 0 stddev, 0 med)
RULES
(
 avg[0,0] = AVG(PRT)[ANY, flag<>1]
 ,stddev[0,0] = STDDEV(PRT)[ANY, flag<>1] 
 ,med[0,0] = PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PRT)[ANY, flag<>1] 
)
) where rown = 0
```

vs standard analytic query:

```
select
intv
,avg(prt) avg
,stddev(prt) stddev
,percentile_cont(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY prt desc) med
from
(
select 
a.*
, val/sum(val) over (partition by rown) prt
, case when avg(val) over (partition by intv) - 2*stddev(val) over (partition by intv) > val then 1 else 0 end flag
from
test a
)
where flag = 0
group by
intv
```

Unfortunately in this moment I do not have access to my big data set, but typically the table these averages would be calculated includes millions of rows. I set up my small db structure in fiddle the following way:

```
create table test (intv number, val number, rown number);
insert all 
into test (intv, val, rown) values (1,5,1)
into test (intv, val, rown) values (1,4,2)
into test (intv, val, rown) values (1,4,3)
into test (intv, val, rown) values (1,5,4)
into test (intv, val, rown) values (1,6,5)
into test (intv, val, rown) values (1,2,6)
into test (intv, val, rown) values (1,5,7)
into test (intv, val, rown) values (1,4,8)
into test (intv, val, rown) values (1,5,9)
into test (intv, val, rown) values (2,10,1)
into test (intv, val, rown) values (2,12,2)
into test (intv, val, rown) values (2,13,3)
into test (intv, val, rown) values (2,15,4)
into test (intv, val, rown) values (2,13,5)
into test (intv, val, rown) values (2,12,6)
into test (intv, val, rown) values (2,19,7)
into test (intv, val, rown) values (2,18,8)
into test (intv, val, rown) values (2,13,9)
select * from dual;
```

What do you think is more efficient for what reason? Which method has what advantage over the other?

I am looking for your answers and best regards!

Comment: I'm sorry but without proper benchmarking this is just going to be opinion. When you have your proper dataset test both and pick the best one.

Comment: So what does the execution plan say?

Answer (score 0):

My own experience of the MODEL clause has led me to never use it for any large data sets. I found it to be extremely slow in comparison to any alternative I could find.

Analytic functions can also be problematic however -- I have found that they are very prone to spelling to disk unless you pay attention to the workarea sizes that they use, and they have pften needed an increase in memory allocation.

That said, you really need to benchmark each one with your own data and RDBMS version.